# Rails belong_to has_many with a custom foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relationship between 2 models in my rails application. I have veered away from the standard of how to implement the relationship as I used another field as a primary key and the naming convention is different. Doing so resulted in the relationship seemingly not being established. I want to understand as to why.

This is a trimmed down version of my models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "alias"
  attr_accessible :alias, :avatar
  has_many :player_sessions, :foreign_key => "player_alias", :class_name => "PlayerSession" 
end

class PlayerSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :player_alias, :total_score
  belongs_to :player, :foreign_key  => "player_alias", :class_name => "Player" 
end
```

The `Player` model has the field `alias` which is the username in my application. I wanted the username to act as the primary key since it is unique and it would be easier to migrate the data and maintain relationships.

Originally I only had PlayerSession model with data already filled in, but as my application grew I added the Player model and simply inserted a row with the same `alias`.

In the `Player`'s `show` view I have the following code:

```
Player Sessions:
<% @player.player_sessions do |player_session| %>
<ul>
    <li><h4>Highest Score:</h4> <%= player_session.total_score %> </li>
</ul>
```

When I try to access the page it simple doesn't show the information.

Other information I can add is that I haven't added any relationships in the database itself.

I am still new to rails and still playing around with it. Any opinions that concern coding standards(outside from answering the question) are welcome.

---

**Update** I have implemented Babur Usenakunov's suggestion by adding the `primary_key` option in the models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "alias"
  attr_accessible :alias, :avatar
  has_many :player_sessions, :primary_key => "alias", :foreign_key => "player_alias", :class_name => "PlayerSession" 
end

class PlayerSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :player_alias, :total_score
  belongs_to :player, :primary_key => "alias", :foreign_key  => "player_alias", :class_name => "Player" 
end
```

Also to test out the the data is valid I acquired the PlayerSession list manually:

Code implemented in controller:

```
@player_sessions =  PlayerSession.where("player_alias = ?", params[:id])
```

Code implemented in view(which outputs the data):

```
<% @player_sessions.each do |player_session| %>
<ul>
    <li><h4>Highest Score:</h4> <%= player_session.total_score %> </li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you should pass primary key in options as well. E.g. `has_many :player_sessions, :primary_key => 'alias', :foreign_key => 'player_alias' :class_name => 'PlayerSession'` and `belongs_to :player, :primary_key => 'alias', :foreign_key  => "player_alias", :class_name => "Player"`

Comment: Tried it that way but still doesn't work

Comment: @Drahcir, I am inclined to think Babur Usenakunov's suggestion should have worked. What does `@player.player_sessions` return after you tried their suggestion?

Comment: @Sunxperous it turns out that it was a silly mistake that caused the issue. Please see the answer below. (I have yet to wait till to tomorrow to mark it as answered).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have solved the issue, it was a matter of adding `each` in the loop I implemented in the view:

```
<% @player.player_sessions.each do |player_session| %>
<ul>
    <li><h4>Highest Score:</h4> <%= player_session.total_score %> </li>
</ul>    
<% end %>
```

After playing around a bit, I realised i didn't need to add the primary_key option in either of the views, and left the foreign key option only in the `Player` model.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "alias"
  attr_accessible :alias, :avatar
  has_many :player_sessions, :foreign_key => "player_alias", :class_name => "PlayerSession" 
end

class PlayerSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :player_alias, :total_score
  belongs_to :player, :class_name => "Player" 
end
```

Comment: Can you help me with this one ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047920/rails-belongs-to-with-custom-column-name

Answer (score 3):

If your PlayerSession table has a column named `alias` then your foreign key should also be `alias`, not `player_alias`. As a token of advice I'd be wary of using an alias as a foreign_key: if your player can/decide to change his alias then all PlayerSession records within your database will become invalid and require an update. Using an immutable parameter such as `player_id` would be preferable to using the existing alias column IMHO.

Comment: The alias is the player's username. So it cannot be changed. It's like deciding to change your email address and keeping all your emails