# Rails belongs_to with custom column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with a legacy database that gives the following schema for the tables `product` and `familia_producto` (`rake db:schema:dump`)

```
create_table "producto", primary_key: "barcode", force: true do |t|
  t.string  "codigo_corto",         limit: 16,               null: false
  t.string  "marca",                limit: 35
  t.string  "descripcion",          limit: 50
  t.string  "contenido",            limit: 10
  t.string  "unidad",               limit: 10
  t.float   "stock",                           default: 0.0
  t.float   "precio"
  t.float   "precio_neto"
  t.float   "costo_promedio"
  t.float   "fifo"
  t.float   "vendidos"
  t.boolean "aplica_iva"
  t.integer "otros_impuestos",      limit: 2
  t.integer "familia",              limit: 2,  default: 1,   null: false
  t.integer "id_tipo_producto",     limit: 2,                null: false
  t.boolean "es_perecible"
  t.float   "dias_stock",                      default: 1.0
  t.float   "margen_promedio",                 default: 0.0
  t.boolean "es_venta_fraccionada"
  t.float   "stock_pro",                       default: 0.0
  t.float   "tasa_canje",                      default: 1.0
  t.float   "precio_mayor"
  t.float   "cantidad_mayor"
  t.boolean "es_mayorista"
  t.boolean "estado"
  t.boolean "precio_editable"
end

create_table "familia_producto", force: true do |t|
  t.string "nombre", limit: 32, null: false
end
```

In the models I've this

```
class FamiliaProducto < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'familia_producto'
  has_many :productos, :class_name => 'Producto', :primary_key => 'barcode', :foreign_key => 'familia'
end

class Producto < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'producto'
  belongs_to :familia_producto, :class_name => 'FamiliaProducto'
end
```

But when I call the `.familia` the producto object throws me a number, not the `FamiliaProducto` object.

```
2.1.0 :012 >   p = Producto.all[0]
  Producto Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "producto".* FROM "producto"
  => #<Product......
2.1.0 :013 > p.familia
  => 2
```

That `2` should be the `FamiliaProducto` object.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You must use the name of the association, also need to add the foreign key to the `belongs_to`

```rb
class Producto < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :familia_producto, class_name: 'FamiliaProducto', foreign_key: 'familia'
end
```

```rb
class FamiliaProducto < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :productos, class_name: 'Producto', foreign_key: 'familia'
end
```

```rb
p = Producto.first

# Returns a FamiliaProducto object
p.familia_producto

# Returns an integer
p.familia
```