# Rails - Columns pointing to same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, rails-activerecord

I have a database with tables `containers` and `ports`.

The `containers` table has two columns `pol_id` and `pod_id` that both point to the `ports` table. The `ports` table has an `id` column.

I have tried using `belongs_to / references` inside the migration but it does not provide such flexibility.

Also, I am a bit puzzled at configuring the models for this.

Comment: show code in your container and port model

Comment: I think you juste want to specify the foreign_key in your belongs_to association.

Comment: Here is a good answer for your model configuration : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047920/rails-belongs-to-with-custom-column-name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `foreign_key` option when creating the migration to customize the foreign key:

```
t.references(:pol, foreign_key: { to_table: :ports })
```

In your model you need to tell ActiveRecord what class the association points to:

```
class Container
  belongs_to :pol, class_name: "Port"
end
```

You also need to provide the foreign key when creating the inverse association:

```
class Port
   has_many :containers_as_pol, class_name: "Container", foreign_key: "pol_id"
end
```

Comment: Note that the belongs_to in migrations is just an alias for references so the same applies.