# One-to-one relationship with variable case string keys in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working with legacy database here, can't change the tables.

Have two tables. Lets say `User` and `Admin`. They both have `user_id` which is a string, and the case varies between the tables. I can pull out records by doing `donwcase` but its a manual query with no fancy ActiveRecord assosiation goods

How can I connect the two models?

I know that you can supply lambda to `has_one` and `belongs_to`, except it is used to narrow down the search, not to replace the AR generated one.

I am considering creating views on those tables and lowering the `user_id` in them. That could work if I dont figure out how to get this going

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047920/rails-belongs-to-with-custom-column-name

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer yes. They had problems with the column names. I have an issue with `user_id` in `Admin` being `FooBar` and `user_id` in `User` being `FOOBAR`