# Using Custom Attribute as Foreign Key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

We have two models, `Question` and `Answer` which are associated:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :answer
end

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to: question
end
```

Under the default setting, the `answers` table contains a `question_id` column which is used for this relation. This column holds the automatic enumeration of the questions (`question.id`), but it presents us some challenges when coming to migrate some old data sets.

Each question has an additional unique identifier called `name`, which is a string:

```
<Question id: 355, name: "ABC123", question_type: ...>
```

We would like to use this attribute as the key for this association. That is, the `answers` table should contain a `question_name` column, which will hold the relevant value. We've managed to set up the custom column name and define foreign keys properly, but it always looks for the `question_id` value rather than the name. Using the above example, it will look for the row where the foreign key is `355` rather than `"ABC123"`.

Is there any way of setting this thing without changing `question`'s primary key (as explained [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions))? I could obviously override the default association methods (question.answer, answer.question) but then again I'd really like not to.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is actually pretty simple (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047920/rails-belongs-to-with-custom-column-name) post):

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :answer, foreign_key: "question_name", primary_key: "name"
 end
    
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :question, foreign_key: "question_name", primary_key: "name"
end
```

The foreign and primary key values could be specified either as strings or symbols.