# Rails belongs_to or has_one association with custom name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to create association between active record objects with custom name.

For example, I have a `User` table and `Post` class, and `Post` class has `writer_id` and `reader_id`. I want to create association for both `writer_id` and `reader_id` so that I can just call `post.writer` to get the `User` object. I have tried multiple options (one of them: [Rails belongs_to with custom column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047920/rails-belongs-to-with-custom-column-name)), but it did not solve the problem. Anyone knows how to unblock this issue?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :reader, class_name: 'User'
end
```

sorry, initially I put `class` instead of `class_name`

Comment: my pleasure xor :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should be using `belongs_to` since the foreign key should be stored on the posts table:

```ruby
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, 
    class_name: 'User'
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.references :author, 
        null: false, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts_as_author,
    class_name: 'Post',
    foreign_key: :author_id
end
```

This creates a one to many assocation. Note that the `foreign_key` option is required in the `has_many` assocation since its normally derived from the name of the class.

`has_one` wouldn't work since it means that you would be storing a `post_id` on the `users` table. `has_one` always has a corresponding `belongs_to` on the other side of the assocation. `has_one` is basically just `has_many` with a `LIMIT 1` tacked onto the query and generates slighly different methods.

When it comes to readers I can almost guarentee what you actually want is a many to many assocation.